# Cannot subscript a value of type '[APISKeyObjects]' with an index of type 'String'?

Tags: ios, json, swift, dynamic, codable

I'm trying to to access the description key in my APIKeyObjects, but I have been getting multiple issues through the syntax.

```
struct NewsApiObject: Codable
{
    let status: String?
    let totalResults: Int?


    let articles: [APISKeyObjects]
}

struct Source: Codable
{
    var id: String?
    var int: Int?
}

struct APISKeyObjects: Codable
{
    let source: Source?
    let author: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let url: String?
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: String?
    let content: String?

}
```

I received the following error message when I attempt to assign "description" which is an optional String in my Struct named "APIKeyObjects"

Error message: "Cannot subscript a value of type [APIKeyObjects] with an index of type 'String'"

```
  let financesNewsData = try JSONDecoder().decode(NewsApiObject.self, from: data)
```

Right after I'm trying to assign the variable to a UITextView Property named UITextDisplay which only accepts String..

```
UITextDisplay.text = financesNewsData.articles[description]
```

Error message: "Cannot subscript a value of type [APIKeyObjects] with an index of type 'String'"

So my question is; what's the proper way to cast it in order to assign the string value to a string property?

Comment: I think you need to read up on arrays (and perhaps other collection types), https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `String var`, it should be `var variableName = ...`

And in your scenario, it should be:

// To get all articles:

```
var articles = financesNewsData.articles
```

// If you want to get a description of an article then

```
let description = articles[index].desccription
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt response! My apologize for the typos, I just noticed I had some typos in my post, cleared out some stuff in order to better explain myself. If you have any further resolution, look forward to see it! Thanks again!

Comment: @AmauryC. Read this answer again, it will resolve your error.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what answer? Are you referring to the links that you placed in??

Comment: No, _this_ answer. You need to use an integer index